# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier$Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to add a Google sign-in button in my Java Web Application project. I'm trying to receive in Servlet back-end  an id token using **GoogleIdTokenVerifier**, following Google Guides: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth. Everything for Eclipse is okay, but running my project using Tomcat v9 and arriving to the point :

```
final HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();// tried it with jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory).setAudience(id_singleton).build();
```

Eclipse gives me this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.GoogleTokenSignIn] in context with path [/Project] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier$Builder.
```

I turned over all the stack overflow and I found an answer which says to update the jars. I have the google api ***release 1.30.9*** jars and ***1.30.6*** or the ***oauth*** and still giving same error.

I don't know how to show my eclipse configuration:
Run configuration
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzwGO.png)
[Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjXz.png)
[Classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlyOt.png)
.
I hope it's clear now.

Comment: your configuration in eclipse is not shown here. add the ecplise settings here to make it more clear if your classpath is properly configured

Comment: What do you mean with my eclipse settings ?!

Comment: If you give me the steps to show what I didn't report, I would show it ☺️.

Answer (score 0):

Take the jar files that causes the issue and extract them, take source and put it in the same directory of your project **/project/src** manually. It should work.